# Java Applet exits and tray icon vanishes after some time, is there any timeout settings?

Tags: java, browser, applet, timeout, trayicon

When i close Java Applet (java 1.6.23) in the browser (IE7, Windows XP) e.g. by the javascript 
Why java.exe and Java tray icon is removed after sometime (one minute or so) ? Is there any timeout value which can be setted somewhere ?

We are experiencing sometimes performance problems with applets, sometimes applets are completly frozen : That`s why i am investigating this "timeout" issue.

Comment: *"When i close Java Applet (java 1.6.23) in the browser (IE7, Windows XP) e.g. by the javascript"*  Don't close applets using JS.  Either navigate to a different page or close that tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any timeout value which can be setted somewhere ?

Not that I know of.  It is really up to the browser/JRE combo. to decide when to end the VM.

Further, if the applet has problems, they will not be solved by setting a 'timeout'.